# Create a lookup field in salesforce using metadata api c#

Tags: metadata-api, metadata, c#

> I am using metadata api with c#. Below code is not giving me an error but still it is not creatng the field in salesforce. Please suggest.

```
                    CF = new MetadataAPI.CustomField();
                    CF.description = "invoices";
                    CF.fullName = "mynamespace__" + co.fullName + "." + Fields[i].Replace(" ", "_") + "__c"; 
                    CF.label = "invoices";
                    CF.type = MetadataAPI.FieldType.Lookup;
                    CF.referenceTo = "Opportunity";
                    CF.relationshipLabel = "invoices";
                    CF.relationshipName = "invoices";
                    CF.relationshipOrderSpecified = false;
                    ASyncResCFS = MetadataSvc.create(new CustomField [] {CF});
```

Comment: Have you checked the SaveResult that the `create` method returns for errors?

Comment: Yes I did but it says no error. I am able to create other type of fields but not lookup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tried to replicate with the following code:

```
MetadataService metadataService = salesforceSession.GetMetadataService();

string fieldName = "testLookup";
string SFType = "Account";

CustomField cf = new CustomField();
cf.fullName = SFType + "." + fieldName + "__c";
cf.type = FieldType.Lookup;
cf.typeSpecified = true;
cf.label = fieldName + " label";
cf.referenceTo = "Opportunity";
cf.relationshipLabel = "Test Accounts";
cf.relationshipName = "test";
cf.relationshipOrderSpecified = false;
cf.lengthSpecified = false;

SaveResult[] saveResults = metadataService.createMetadata(new CustomField[] { cf });

Assert.IsTrue(saveResults[0].success);

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(saveResults[0].fullName);
```

The SaveResult was successful and returned the fullName. One thing to note, by org was a developer edition and it did have a namespace defined. Yet I didn't need to include that namespace in the code and it didn't come back in the fullName.

I was using v40.0 of the Metadata API.

[image: Created Lookup field via Metadata API]